# Magento 2 EE Order By Sku Widget Template not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento-ee

Magento 2 EE version provide default Order By SKU widget but it's not working with default luma theme please check attached screenshot.

[image]

Steps

> Go to Admin => Content => pages => home page => add Order By SKU
> widget

I have facing this in **Magento EE 2.3.5** and **Magento EE 2.4.0**

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about magento core implementation of the functionnality, but I'm using a custom method to do this. Feel free to call the result in a custom template and to adopt the data returned in the array.

```
/**
 * @return array|string
 */
public function getCollectionOrders()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('sku')) {
        $sku = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sku');
        $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        $collection->getSelect()
            ->join(
                ["soi" => $collection->getTable("sales_order_item")],
                'main_table.entity_id = soi.order_id',
                array('sku')
            )
            ->where("soi.sku like = ? ", $sku);

        $collection->setOrder(
            'created_at',
            'desc'
        );

        $arrayOrders = array();

        foreach ($collection as $order) {
            $arrayOrders[] = array(
                'entity_id' => $order->getEntityId(),
                'id' => $order->getIncrementId(),
                'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname() . ' ' . $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname(),
                'shipping' => $order->getShippingAddress()->getLastname() . ' ' . $order->getShippingAddress()->getFirstname(),
                'status' => $order->getStatus(),
                'sku' => $sku
            );
        }

        return $arrayOrders;
    }

    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you ever able to solve this problem. for me its working on one store but showing same error as yours on other store.